# Remove nodes from Linked List based on a value

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I am working through a Hackerrank problem and I am trying to remove all nodes that are greater than a particular value.

This is their basic implementation

```
const SinglyLinkedListNode = class{
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
};

const SinglyLinkedList = class {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
  }

  insertNode(value) {
    const node = new SinglyLinkedListNode(value);
    if(!this.head) {
      this.head = node;
    } else {
      this.tail.next = node;
    }
    this.tail = node;
  }
};
```

My function to removeNodes is as follows...

```
SinglyLinkedList.prototype.removeNodes = function(listHead, x){
  let currentNode = listHead;

  while(currentNode !== null && currentNode.next !== null) {
    let next = currentNode.next;
    while (next !== null && next.value > x) {
      next = next.next
    }
    currentNode.next = next
    if(currentNode.next === null) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return currentNode
}
```

The parameters are: listhead - reference to the root node, and x - the integer value to filter the Linked List

So for example, the LL is 1-> 2 -> 4 -> 3 -> 5 and I need to remove all nodes greater than x (3) and maintain the integrity of the LL order.
The result should be 1 -> 2 -> 3.

I am getting confused on why I keep getting this.tail.value = 5 instead of 
this.tail.value = 3, this.tail.next = null.

this is a [REPL](https://repl.it/@super996/Remove-Nodes-Linked-List)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause the `tail` has to be rewritten explicitly as it keeps a reference to an unlinked node otherwise. Before running the function the list looks like:

```
  list: head                                   tail
           1    ->    2   ->    3  ->    4    ->  5
```

and afterwards the tail still points to 5 although that was unlinked:

```
 list: head                                  tail
         1    ->    2   ->    3             5
```

To resolve this, just rewrite the tail at the end of your function:

```
 return this.tail = currentNode;
```

Also you have to actually traverse the list, so add a

```
 currentNode = currentNode.next;
```

at the end of the outer `while`.

Comment: Ok, however it seems that if console.log(this.tail.next), I still don't see null. The reference is still pointing to 4

Comment: @kevin oh and you messed up the list traversal, see [this](https://jsbin.com/hatewevodo/edit?console)